# Changing Number Font Into Sans Serif

Tags: fonts, numbering, libertine, sans-serif

I want to use **Libertine Sans Serif** **numbers** (only numbers) in math font.
Can i get this result using a command like this:

```
    \DeclareSymbolFont{numbers}{T1}{libertine}{m}{n}
    \SetSymbolFont{numbers}{bold}{T1}{libertine}{bx}{n}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{0}\mathalpha{numbers}{"30}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{1}\mathalpha{numbers}{"31}
    .
    .
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{libertine}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[libertine,liby,libaltvw,vvarbb]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%\DeclareSymbolFont{numbers}{T1}{libertine-SF}{m}{n}
%\SetSymbolFont{numbers}{bold}{T1}{libertine-SF}{bx}{n}
%\DeclareMathSymbol{0}\mathalpha{numbers}{"30}
%\DeclareMathSymbol{1}\mathalpha{numbers}{"31}
%\DeclareMathSymbol{2}\mathalpha{numbers}{"32}
%\DeclareMathSymbol{3}\mathalpha{numbers}{"33}
%\DeclareMathSymbol{4}\mathalpha{numbers}{"34}
%\DeclareMathSymbol{5}\mathalpha{numbers}{"35}
%\DeclareMathSymbol{6}\mathalpha{numbers}{"36}
%\DeclareMathSymbol{7}\mathalpha{numbers}{"37}
%\DeclareMathSymbol{8}\mathalpha{numbers}{"38}
%\DeclareMathSymbol{9}\mathalpha{numbers}{"39}

\begin{document}

\noindent 1234567890 TEXT\\
$1234567890$ MATH\\
is it possible to make numbers in math as in text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. But confront your line 2 with `\SetSymbolFont{numbers}{bold}{T1}{phv}{bx}{n}`: it may be necessary a 3-digit string like `phv` to identify the font (libertine in your case).

Comment: Please, make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228); it's important to know how you load the Libertine fonts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The internal font family name for the sans serif font is available as `\biolinum@family`. The string `numbers` would probably be good, but I prefer to call it `sfnumbers`.

Note that `\familydefault` is usually defined as `\long`, so `\renewcommand` should be used, not `\renewcommand*`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{libertine}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} % not *
\usepackage[libertine,liby,libaltvw,vvarbb]{newtxmath}

\makeatletter
\DeclareSymbolFont{sfnumbers}{T1}{\biolinum@family}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{sfnumbers}{bold}{T1}{\biolinum@family}{b}{n}
\makeatother
\DeclareMathSymbol{0}\mathalpha{sfnumbers}{"30}
\DeclareMathSymbol{1}\mathalpha{sfnumbers}{"31}
\DeclareMathSymbol{2}\mathalpha{sfnumbers}{"32}
\DeclareMathSymbol{3}\mathalpha{sfnumbers}{"33}
\DeclareMathSymbol{4}\mathalpha{sfnumbers}{"34}
\DeclareMathSymbol{5}\mathalpha{sfnumbers}{"35}
\DeclareMathSymbol{6}\mathalpha{sfnumbers}{"36}
\DeclareMathSymbol{7}\mathalpha{sfnumbers}{"37}
\DeclareMathSymbol{8}\mathalpha{sfnumbers}{"38}
\DeclareMathSymbol{9}\mathalpha{sfnumbers}{"39}

\begin{document}

\noindent 1234567890 TEXT\\
$1234567890$ MATH\\
is it possible to make numbers in math as in text.

\end{document}
```

[image]