# How to change the font of the numbers specifically (not in equations)?

Tags: fonts

I have a font choice:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{merriweather}
```

and I would like to change the font of the numbers used in the text and when I reference figures and equations (with `\ref{fig:coolPic}`). The question [linkhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/185172/1026) describes putting math fonts into the normal numerical text fonts but I want to choose the font independently for the number uses.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "change the font of the numbers used in the text and when I reference figures and equations". E.g., do you want to you want to use sans-serif numerals (from the merriweather package, presumably) everywhere in the text? Or should sans-serif numerals be used only while cross-referencing `figure` and `equation` objects? What about cross-references to tables, sections, theorems, etc: should the associated numerals be using serif or sans-serif numerals?

Comment: @mico, the ability to choose different number font in the text body; not equations etc

Comment: This doesn't answer my questions. Do you want to use sans-serif numerals *everywhere* in text mode, or just when creating cross-referencing call-outs?

Comment: Everywhere in text mode. Not in other parts

Comment: @Mico, if possible would I be able to set those two separately? If not, using a new font for the numerals in the text and cross referencing call outs is also great to know

Comment: I'm afraid your intended document setup is still a mystery to me. For sure, the instruction `\usepackage[sfdefault]{merriweather}` loads the `Merriweather Sans` font and makes it the default text font. (The math font hasn't been changed, though.) With this setup, all text-mode numerals will automatically by typeset using the glyphs provided by `Merriweather Sans`. (These numerals are so-called "oldstyle" or "lowercase" numerals, by the way.) Are you dissatisfied with these numerals? If so, which alternative set of numerals would you like to employ?

Comment: @Mico, yes, exactly the typeset for the numerals are not suitable for easy reading. Any numeral fonts which are more clear and stand out easily would be preferable