# Change numbers in math mode to sans serif

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I am using pdflatex to create a scientific document and I'd like to know if there is a way to change the font of **numbers** in math equations to a sans serif type.

Right now with the following font settings the combination of serif numbers and sans serif units looks weird imo.

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[scaled]{uarial}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

[image]

I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185172/changing-number-font-into-sans-serif) solution but is this the best way to do it ?

Comment: I don't recommend the uarial package. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309100/arial-font-baseline-for-letters-i-and-l.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest PDFLaTeX-compatible approach is to load `mathastext`, which uses your text font for letters and numerals in math mode.  Another is to load a sans-serif math font, such as the `newtxsf` package.

If you are allowed to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, they give you more choices.

Comment: Thank you, I will use the `newtxsf` package although it converts the complete math font to sans serif not only the numbers but I guess that looks cleaner than using a mixture of both types...

Comment: @LaTeX_Ghost I guessed so too, and I guessed that's what you wanted. If you want to change only numbers, `mathastext` does have a couple of options for the digits.

Comment: @LaTeX_Ghost For example, you could start with `newtexsf`, then load `newtxtext` or `tgtermes`, then `\usepackage[nodigits]{mathastext}` to replace the letters but not the digits.